# Select lists from a nested list such that each list contains a specific pattern appeared within certain position offset?

Tags: list-manipulation

Say a nested list `datatest` and a sublist `searchterm`, I would like to pick up the lists in the `datatest` which contains `searchterm` and `searchterm` appears in the first position (allowing maximal offset 5) of each lists in `datatest`.

For example:

```
datatest = {{8, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3}, 
{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11}, {4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3}};

searchterm={1,2,3,6};
```

I would like to have the results

> {{8, 5, 1, **1, 2, 3, 6**, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, **1, 2, 3, 6**, 2, 3, 1, 3}, {4, 5, 1, **1, 2, 3, 6**, 1, 1, 2, 4}}

term `{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, **1, 2, 3, 6**, 11}` **is not fulfilled since it appears in the position 6, which is >5.**

My way is following (not a good method, results are in `Selectdata`):

```
datatest = {{8, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11}, 
{4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3}};
searchterm= {1, 2, 3, 6};

pos = Flatten[Map[First /@ SequencePosition[#, searchterm] &]@datatest];
pickpos = Select[pos, # < 5 &]; (*pick up only offset position is below 5*)

Selectdata = {};
count = 0;
For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[pickpos], ii++,
 
 index = Flatten[Position[pos, pickpos[[ii]]]];
 If[Length[index] == 1,
     AppendTo[Selectdata, datatest[[index[[1]]]]],
     count++;
     AppendTo[Selectdata, datatest[[index[[count]]]]];
  ];
 ]
```

The above code only works for the defined `datatest` (use `count++` might not work generally) . So is there any simple solution or more general way to do it when `datatest` gets large?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases):

```
Cases[datatest, {z__, Sequence @@ searchterm, ___} /; Length[{z}] < 5]
```

> {{8, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3}, {4, 5, 1,
> 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}}

Comment: I have used Cases before but didn’t do the trick z__ and length[z]<5. That’s good trick! Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) and specify *maximal offset* using [`Repeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html):

```
Cases[{Repeated[_, 5 - 1], Sequence @@ searchterm, ___}] @ datatest
```

> {{8, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3}, {4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}}

Comment: that's also a nice solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
datatest//Pick[#,MatchQ[#,{___,1,2,3,6,___}]&/@#[[All,;;8]],True]&)
```

> {{8, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3},

> {4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}}

Answer (score 1):

```
test =
  {{8, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4},
   {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3},
   {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11},
   {4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4},
   {1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3}};

term = {1, 2, 3, 6};

sel[x_] /; SequencePosition[x, term] === {} := Nothing
sel[x_] /; SequencePosition[x, term][[1, 1]] > 5 := Nothing
sel[x_] := x

sel /@ test
```

{{8, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1,
3}, {4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}}

Answer (score 1):

```
datatest = {{8, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 
    3, 1, 3}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11}, {4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 
    1, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3}};

searchterm = {1, 2, 3, 6};

Cases[datatest[[All, 1 ;; 4 + Length[searchterm]]], {___, 
  searchterm /. List -> Sequence, ___}]
```

> {{8, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1}, {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 1, 1, 2,
> 3, 6, 1}}

```
Cases[datatest[[All, 1 ;; 4 + Length[searchterm]]], 
 Flatten@{___, searchterm, ___}]
```

> {{8, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1}, {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 1, 1, 2,
> 3, 6, 1}}